# how to send the data of two individual contact form via mail through ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I am working on a project. I am using HTML5 and other UI libraries.
It's a one-page layout website. I have two contact forms. first is sponsorship request form and another one for general contact/query form. I need to handle these two forms (Sponsorship form and contact us form)  independently. So I am using Ajax and PHP for sending mail to my business email.

When I had only one contact form ... I tested the application on a live server. everything was working fine. Now, I added a new form, problems start rising...

I am using two js (sponsorship.js  and contact_me.js) scripts and two PHP (Sponsorship.php and contact_me.php) scripts for mail, but the thing is that I am getting the response from one script when I am sending data from one contact from. but when I am trying to submit the data from both forms I get the error below in the developer console.

Failed to load sponsorship.php, Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

```
 failed to load contact_me.php , Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

### below is my code

### Sponsorship html code

```
          <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" style="height:60px;" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Valid Email" style="height:60px;" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Valid Phone Number " style="height:60px;" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Job Title" style="height:60px;" id="jobTitle" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Job Title.">
                                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Company" style="height:60px;" id="company" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Company.">
                                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select name="countries" 
              class="form-control" style="height:60px;" id="coutries" required>
                                            <option value="-1">Select Country</option>
                                            <option value="United States">United States</option>
                                            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                                            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>

                                        </select>
                                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                    <div id="success"></div>
                                    <br>
                                    <button type="submit" id="Sponsorreq" 
                                   class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 50px; width:300px;">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

### sponsorship.js

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#Sponsorreq").click(function() {
           $("input,select").jqBootstrapValidation({
   preventSubmit: true,
  submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
    // additional error messages or events
  },
  submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
    // get values from FORM
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    var jobTitle = $("input#jobTitle").val();
    var company = $("input#company").val();
    var country = $("select#country").val();
    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    if (firstName.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
      firstName = name
        .split(" ")
        .slice(0, -1)
        .join(" ");
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: "././mail/Sponsor.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        jobtitle: jobTitle,
        company: company,
        country: country
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
        // Success message
        $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
        $("#success > .alert-success")
          .html(
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
          )
          .append("</button>");
        $("#success > .alert-success").append(
          "<strong> Thankyou...Your Sponsor request has been sent.We will contact you shortly </strong>"
        );
        $("#success > .alert-success").append("</div>");

        //clear all fields
        $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
      },
      error: function() {
        // Fail message
        $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
        $("#success > .alert-danger")
          .html(
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
          )
          .append("</button>");
        $("#success > .alert-danger").append(
          "<strong>Sorry " +
            firstName +
            ", it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"
        );
        $("#success > .alert-danger").append("</div>");
        //clear all fields
        $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
      }
    });
  },
  filter: function() {
    return $(this).is(":visible");
  }
});

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab("show");
   });
  });
      /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
    $("#name").focus(function() {
     $("#success").html("");
     });
       });
```

### sponsorship.php

```
    <?php
  // Check for empty fields
 if(empty($_POST['name'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['jobTitle'])    ||
    empty($_POST['company'])     ||
    empty($_POST['country'])        ||
    !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
     {
      echo "No arguments Provided!";
     return false;
     }

     $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email_address = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $jobTitle = $_POST['jobTitle'];
         $company = $_POST['company'];
            $country = $_POST['country'];
    // Create the email and send the message
                 $to = 'info@bangkokblockchainconference.com'; // Add your 
                   email address inbetween the '' replacing 
                  yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
            $email_subject = "Website Sponsor Form:  $name";
          $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website 
           Sponsor form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: 
           $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nJob 
             Title:\n$jobTitle\n\nCompany:\n$company\n\nCountry:\n$country";
           $headers = "From: noreply@bangkokblockchainconference.com\n"; // 
               This is the email address the generated message will be from. 
            We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
                $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
                mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
                  return true;          
               ?>
```

contact.js and contact.php follow the same logic.

The code is not working...

Mailing is not working...

Comment: do you using chrome browser ?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid  yes I am using chrome

Comment: did you already tried to file access problem fix in chrome browser ? sometimes file load problem happen in chrome browser in locally, but not in live server.

Comment: @EmtiazZahid  I tried the to check on the live server as well same results

Comment: @EmtiazZahid Here is the live link
http://watal.000webhostapp.com

Comment: Are you sure this is the sponsorship form? Because from what I am seeing it has the contact form Id even though I didn't see your contact form code. But you can't have both forms with the same Id in the same page.
This error indicates that they have different domain names. Means the HTML page along with the js resides in a different domain from your PHP endpoint, thus the cross-origin error.

Comment: @mohessaid  I got it working.. But now contact form is working fine.. Sponsors form email failure.. Mail is not working

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to change the forms IDs. You can't have the same ID used more than once in the same page.
And then to fix your issue. You have to update the `url` in your Ajax request to the current domain. The current value `././` is wrong. Instead, you can change it with `./mail/`. I got it working after updating the URLs.
[image]